# Set dynamic width to a div according to the width of the previous span

Tags: html, css

I have two elements; viz a span and then a div. The contents of the span should have maximium of length 25 to 30 characters and the contents of the div can be a paragraph (and both contents are dynamic). What my customer wants is to set the width of the div is same as that of the span (no issues with height). Right now i implemented this with JS and is working fine, can we do the same with CSS so that my life will be more easier ?

Thanks for the reply.

Tismon Varghese.

Edit : Please see the code below

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="summary-headder"> Header Header Header Header Header </span>
<div class="summary-comment" style="width: 495px;">
    test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment          
</div>
</div>

var summary_headder_width  = $('.summary-headder').width();

$('.summary-comment').css('width', summary_headder_width + 'px');
```

Comment: Please see the code in edit section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it would be to have your wrapper displayed as a table (display:table;) of a fixed 1px width (width:1px;) and have the header overide this width with white-space:nowrap. The following div, not overiding the width would follow its sibbling width.

```
div.wrapper {
    display:table;
    width:1px;
}

span.summary-header {
    display:table-row;
    background-color:green;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

div.summary-comment {
    display:table-row;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ubu/1/) for a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<div style="display: table">
   <span style="display: table-row">Test text test text test text</span>
   <div style="display: table-row; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; float: left">test</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8eT/

Comment: This won't work, I've forked your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dK5Qu/1/) to demonstrate a bad result test case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a table
http://jsfiddle.net/zNJ34/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header Header Header Header Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment test comment</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The table path seems to be right, but your solution doesn't answers @user2869757 's question. The way I understand it, he wants to have the <td>'s width automatically match the <th>'s width, not the opposite.